# How to let Chartboost display only video Interstitial?

Tags: chartboost

In the new version of Chartboost iOS SDK, `showInterstitial` will display video or image Interstitial, how to make it `showInterstitial` display image Interstital & `showInterstitialVideo` display video Interstitial? I pop up an Interstitial when app become active, it's not welcome to users that display a 10 seconds video Interstitial.

Can I set the CBLocation on the website to let the `showInterstitial` display image or video,e.g `showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu` only for video? But I failed because `CBLocationMainMenu` also displays image Interstital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chartboost dashboard, you can add campaign(s) to your app to show interstitial. If you added 2 campaigns to your app, one with Ad Type set to static interstitial, and the other one with Ad Type set to video interstitial; and you call showInterstitial with the a location name that exists in both campaigns, then your interstitial may be image or video.

If you only want to show only image interstitial when your app starts, you can do it in two ways.

1) Add only one campaign (with Ad Type set to static interstitial) or

2) Use both static interstitial and video interstitial campaigns for you app. Go to the video campaign and at the Game Logic part, choose the location that you only want to show image, and tick the checkbox of Never Show. You can find the Never Show checkbox next to the priority drop-down.

You can configure on the dashboard to make your app only show video interstitial in similar way.

Also, the official document provided this information:

> You can configure the rest of the campaign as normal, but publishers
>   should note that – because the call to show an interstitial video is
>   the same as the call to show a static interstitial – you should set an
>   interstitial video campaign to a higher priority than other campaigns
>   running at the same named location if you want to show a video ad
>   first.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've set only "Main Menu(1 App)" to video and `never show` "Main Menu(1 App)" to image interstitial. But still showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu will display video. Higher priority I've also set, but not work. The first one of your advices is good for only display image interstitial, but I need to use video interstitial at other place.

Comment: @Gank You have "Main Menu" set to never show for the image interstitial campaign, so when you call showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu, only video interstitial will be displayed. Also, please notice that you can call showInterstitial: with custom location name(eg. showInterstitial:@"level3" ).

Comment: You're right that `call showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu, only video interstitial will be displayed`. And `a higher priority than other campaigns` must be set, too. Thanks very much

Comment: It does not work sometimes. showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu also still display the video ads.

Comment: So actually what you want is calling showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu will only display image interstitial? If that is the case, then you should: 1)go to the video interstitial campaign, and 2)click the "Main Menu" location in Campagin Logic part, and 3)tick the Never Show checkbox next to the Priority drop-down. Next, you need to make sure that for the static interstitial campaign, the Never Show checkbox is not ticked for "Main Menu".

Comment: Yes, I had done that at the time I post the question. I aslo changed the `a higher priority than other campaigns` in "Main Menu" for video ads than images ads. Yesterday it was OK, but today goes wrong. It must be chartboost's bug

Comment: It's strange... Maybe it is a bug. It is working for me. When I tick Never Show for video, only image interstitial comes out. When I tick Never Show for static interstitial, only video interstitial is shown. The priority doesn't matter when using Never Show.

Comment: i want to show video ad at every 4th gameover only and in every 1st,2nd,3rd gameover i wish to show static ad.

Can it possible?

Comment: @SudhirKotila I guess you can have a counter for counting the time of gameover. And add both static interstitial and video interstitial campaigns for your app. Whenever the counter counts to a multiple of 4, call `showInterstitial` with "location1". Otherwise, call `showInterstitial` with "location2". Go to the video campaign and at the Game Logic part, choose "location2", and tick the checkbox of Never Show. Then, go to the static interstitial campaign, and choose "location1" and tick the checkbox of Never Show. The location names are just for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make different campaign for video and static interstitial on your dashboard.

If you want to block all static interstitial, go in this campaign and put a very high bid for CPI and CPC.

That s it

Enjoy